# Get element randomly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array --> **let arr = ['down', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up'];**
I need **third element** to be changed **randomly**, either **'down'** or **'up'**.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: I use javascript

Comment: You should tag your question with the language you're using next time so people can find your question more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random boolean and change the item accordingly:

```js
let arr = ['down', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up'];
var random_boolean = Math.random() >= 0.5;
arr[2] = random_boolean ? 'up' : 'down';
console.log(...arr);
```

Comment: how to change the code if I have this.direction = ['down', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up']; ?

Comment: Is it okay if I get down,  down, dwon/up, up, up   not an array like ['down', 'down', 'down/up', 'up', ''up] ?